# Collapse icon - change not working if have more than three item

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have faced a very strange problem. I use `ng-repeat` where I show data and every data have collapse icon to show more.

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="(key, value) in lists">
    <a ng-click="collapseIt($index)" data-toggle="collapse" href="{{'#collapseExample' + $index}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none">{{key}}
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="{{'collapseExample' + $index}}" class="list" ng-repeat="list in value track by list.id">
        <div ng-if="collapseId==$parent.$index">
            <span>
                <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 0" src="" alt="success" />
                <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 1" src="" alt="warning" />
                <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 2" src="" alt="error" />
            </span>
            <span>
                 <strong>{{list.update_dt}}</strong>
            </span>
            <span>{{list.type}}</span>
            <span>{{list.serial_number}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works if I have only three item (log) but if I have more than **three item**, **collapsable icon change not working**.
Pls, take a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2fg392b/7/)

First three LOG icon change work, but another not. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is small issue with your code. The same id is getting repeated in your code which is causing this issue.

try this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

```
  <div class="logBox" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 250px;">
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="(key, value) in lists">

      <a ng-click="collapseIt($index)" data-toggle="collapse" href="{{'#collapseExample' + $index}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample{{$index}}" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none">{{key}}
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>

    <div id="{{'collapseExample' + $index}}" >


      <div  class="list" ng-repeat="list in value track by list.id">
        <div ng-if="collapseId==$parent.$index">
         ...
        </div>

      </div> </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thank you. Can you pls explain to me way in new parent div this working but not in same with ng-repeat? thnx

Comment: `<div id="{{'collapseExample' + $index}}" class="list" ng-repeat="list in value track by list.id">` used along with ng-repeat so it was taking $index of that `value` loop instead of parent $index.